# AJAX call WebService Parallel maximum process and abort

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, web-services, asmx

i have 2 questions about AJAX and Asynch call to a webservice.

1)
When the page is loaded, 18 AJAX requests fired to a webservice page ASMX. You can see in the following picture, only 6 request are treated at the begining and when one of them are completed, another one is accepted.
[image]

How can I do to increase the maximum number of taks treated at the same time? From 6 to 18.

One of the AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myRetourboxUn;
        function RechercherInterventionboxUn()
        {
            myRetourboxUn = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    timeout: 30000,
                    cache: false,
                    url: "/TestAsynch/InterventionRecherche.asmx/HelloWorld",
                    data: ({}),
                    dataType: "text",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#tdboxUn").children(".divContenu").hide();
                        $("#tdboxUn").children(".divChargement").show();
                    }
            }).done(function(msg){
                $("#tdboxUn").children(".divContenu").show();
                $("#tdboxUn").children(".divChargement").hide();                        
                $("#tdboxUn").children(".divContenu").html("--" + msg);
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $("#tdboxUn").children(".divContenu").show();
                $("#tdboxUn").children(".divChargement").hide();  
                $("#tdboxUn").children(".divContenu").text(textStatus);
            });
            $(".menu").click(function(){
                myRetourboxUn .abort();
            });
        }
        $(function(){
            RechercherInterventionboxUn();
        });
        $(window).unload(function() {
            //myRetourboxUn .abort();
        });
</script>
```

The Webservice code:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class InterventionRecherche
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Dim aTemps As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim aTest As Integer = 1
        Do While aTest < 100000000
            aTest += 1
        Loop
        Return (DateTime.Now - aTemps).ToString
    End Function

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld3() As String
        Dim aTemps As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim aTest As Integer = 1
        Do While aTest < 100000000
            aTest += 1
        Loop
        Return (DateTime.Now - aTemps).ToString
    End Function

End Class
```

2) When I want to refresh the page, it stay frozen until all the request are completed. How to tell to not wait when unload the page and automaticaly abort the requests?

Apparently, this behavior is specific to IE as in Chrome, no problem arises when you want to change page. The requests arrive in error then the page is reloaded immediately

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find an explication an a solution.
For the first part, Internet Explorer 8 & 9 only authorized 6 concurrent connections to the same server, as other browsers but probably in another way because my probleme doesn't exist on Chrome...
[Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)

For the second part, just a few code allow you to abort every call when you want to change the page:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    myretourboxun.abort();
});
```